# How to migrate from bazaar working copy to git

Tags: git, backup, bazaar

Recently my Bazaar server broke.

I'm left only with working copy of my branch.

Is there possibility to migrate this working copy to git repository?

Do I have chance to restore history of commits?

Comment: Is it a lightweight checkout or not? Regular Bazaar checkout contain the whole history and all the content. You just can branch it again or export it to another version control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't bazaar supposed to be a distributed VCS (scm, whatever)? 
You should have the entire repository along with that working tree. (that's how git/hg work)

I may not understand your question, in that case the only thing you can do is git init with no chance to restore the history.